# bootstrap 4 arrange the card horizontally using for each loop

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, card

I have different author  record in the table Author. I want to show the author details in a bootstrap card  to arrange horizontally to show more than one author in a single row . But when I am trying to show  it ,  one author being showed in a row. I am trying to list multiple  record in a row using card.
my code given below.

```
 public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author{ get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }        

}
```

```html
<div class="row">


    @foreach (var author in Model)
    {
        <section id="blog" class="py-3">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                   
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="~/images/blog/blog1.jpeg" class="img-fluid card-img-top" />
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">@author.Title</h4>
                                <small class="text-muted">Written by @author.Author</small>
                                <hr>
                                <p class="card-text">
                                     @Comments
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                   

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a basic rule of the Bootstrap grid...

> "In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and *only*
> columns may be immediate children of rows"

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var author in Model)
    {
        
             <section class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 py-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="~/images/blog/blog1.jpeg" class="img-fluid card-img-top" />
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">@author.Title</h4>
                                <small class="text-muted">Written by @author.Author</small>
                                <hr>
                                <p class="card-text">
                                     @Comments
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
             </section>
            
    }
</div>
```